# Como faço um array de informações do banco de dados em codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Por exemplo, estou mandando um array de id [0] => 1, [1] => 3 e quero mostrar isso no meu html em forma de resultado. No caso, que buscar no banco o com o primeiro id salvar no array e depois buscar com o segundo id e por fim retornar um array contendo os outros dois arrays.

```
    public function getRecibos($codigosRecibo)
{      
    $result = array('');

    foreach ($codigosRecibo as $codigoRecibo)
    {
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->where('idRecibo', $codigoRecibo);
        $this->db->join('cheque', 'cheque.idCheque = recibo.recibo_idCheque', 'left');
        $this->db->from('recibo');
        $result = $this->db->get();
    }       
        return $result->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que basta fazer isso

```
public function getRecibos($codigosRecibo)
{      
    $result = [];

    foreach ($codigosRecibo as $codigoRecibo)
    {
        $result[] = $this->db->query('select * from recibo
                                      where idRecibo = ?
                                      left join cheque
                                      on cheque.idCheque = recibo.recibo_idCheque',
                                      array($codigoRecibo))->row();
    }       
        return $result;
}
```